# How can I remove this (The Workplace) account association from other stack exchange sites so that It cannot be traced back to me at my office?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Most of the people at my office know of my Stack Overflow account. This account (workplace) is associated with my SO account. However, I want to remove this association as this is a danger to my job. I have asked certain questions on Workplace about my job which can get me into trouble.

Comment: Related: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/395/869

Comment: Why are people familiar with your SO account?  That doesn't seem like very necessary information for them to have.

Comment: @Jim also, I feel quite strongly against anonymous posting in general.  Yes, there will always exist some exceptions, but as a general rule I feel that people should be willing to stand behind their words and actions.  In this case, such care would be keeping your SE account information more private...but that doesn't quite remedy pre-existing situations.

Comment: @acolyte While that makes sense for answers, it doesn't really apply to questions. Not standing behind/supporting your answer calls its legitimacy into question. Not wanting it associated with you is a sign that you probably shouldn't have even posted it. For questions, though, it's different. You don't need to back up a request for help any more than writing an answerable, on-topic question.

Comment: @acolyte - If one is an active SO user, then your SO account can be a good thing to show potential employers - it demonstrates your value.

Comment: Related: [Is it a better idea to post at the Workplace with a different account?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/517/is-it-a-better-idea-to-post-at-the-workplace-with-a-different-account) and [How can I ask questions on this site anonymously?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/how-can-i-ask-questions-on-this-site-anonymously)

Comment: see also: [Why separate Stack Exchange accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69422/why-separate-stack-exchange-accounts) at MSE

Answer (score 7):

It is [no longer possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109054/167443) to disassociate one account from another, since accounts are now network level.

> Since all associations are done through credentials, disassociating* doesn't really make sense anymore. It's roughly equivalent to "delete this account", as removing the "associating credentials" would leave the user unusable.
>
> So, in short, it is no longer possible to disassociate accounts.
>
> <sub>*The associate button is still available for debugging purposes, it will be going away eventually</sub>

It is, however, possible to remove association at the post level. If you've got a particular question or answer you'd like disassociated with your account, flag it for moderator attention, and explain that using the "other" option. We will contact the devs to anonymize it ([example](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/8806/869)).

If you don't want future questions associated with your account, you can log out (or use a different browser/incognito browser window) to ask the question as an unregistered user.